# Sending Digital Audio Through GPIO Pins

Tags: gpio, audio, hat

I currently use my raspberry Pi as a Spotify music streamer for my Hifi system. I send digital signal out through the USB port to a Digital to Analog Converter (DAC), and then into an Amp, and finally out of the speakers.

However, I want to attach a SPIDIF output to my Raspberry Pi. The SPDIF output I'm using can be found in this link (https://www.allo.com/sparky/digione.html#downloads), it's a Raspberry Pi Hat... I think that's what they're called. Before I make the purchase I want to make sure I can code my Raspberry Pi to send audio signal through the GPIO to the "Hat".

Does anyone know how to send audio signal from the Raspberry Pi to the GPIO to one of these "Hats"?

Comment: Shouldn't you ask the manufacturer or seller?

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

When you buy Audio HAT from any manufacturer they usually have full documentation.
Even the link you provided shows everything.
These HATs usually work well with any software that can use their interface - try at the beginning Volumio - once you start the Volumio it will ask you which DAC you have - you will provide it there.
Allo shows in the links you provided how to set it up with Dietpi - but any other OS will work, i.e. Raspberry Pi OS or Volumio.